# jquery if statement not working as it should

Tags: jquery, html, if-statement

I have a problem. I have created some code and logically it should work, however everytime i fire it it's not doing what it should be. I will post code below and a jsFiddle, but the main problem is that when a div's value is set to Gold disable a second select box

jquery:

```
$('select[name="Package Options"]').change(function() {
  $('#result').html($(this).find(":selected").val());
  var result = $('#result').val();
  if(result == 'Gold') {
      $('select[name="Bolt On Options"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  }
});
```

jsFiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/andyjh07/xHrHA/

thanks guys

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've made your code far too complicated - there's no need to `.find` the `:selected` value - it's already available as `this.value` in the event handler.

You also need to be able to re-enable the control when another value is picked, so:

```
$('select[name="Package Options"]').change(function () {
    var result = this.value;
    $('#result').html(result);
    $('select[name="Bolt On Options"]').prop('disabled', result === 'Gold');
});
```

NB: you should use `.prop` to change the properties of an existing control instead of `.attr`.  The latter is only supposed to reflect the attributes that exist in the HTML source, although jQuery does have a hack in place for the `disabled` attribute to ensure it works in these circumstances.  The other advantage (as seen here) is that the supplied value is then a boolean, further simplifying the code.

I would also recommend replacing your `select[name="..."]` selectors with simple IDs (which must of course then also be present on the elements).  It'll make your code more readable, giving a final solution as seen below, which is not only much shorter than your original code, but is also much more efficient *and* handles the "reset" back to "enabled" when another option is chosen:

```
$('#package').change(function () {
    var result = this.value;
    $('#result').html(result);
    $('#bolton').prop('disabled', result === 'Gold');
});
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/alnitak/gBMQ9/

Comment: This is good, thank you. I wasn't aware of the fact that i could strip out the selected thing. I have an issue now, where if i select the Gold package, it will disable as requested, but if i then change to say the 1 hour package, it stays disabled. Do you have a solution?

Comment: @AndyHolmes sure - that's even easier!  I'll update in a moment.

Comment: +1 for `.prop()`, and for apparently thinking along exactly the same lines as me. (I'll delete my comments under the question so that they don't distract from this answer.)

Comment: @nnnnnn Thanks - I've done likewise.  By "already" I meant that even though your comments predated my answer and edits, in both cases I had written the text before seeing your comments.

Comment: Yes, sorry, I didn't mean to imply you'd copied my ideas - even aside (there's that word again) from the obviously overlapping timeframes I've seen enough of your other answers to know you don't need to copy.

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `html()` method to retrieve the contents of the element, `#result`.  `val()` is primarily used for retrieving the value of form elements.

```
$('select[name="Package Options"]').change(function() {
  $('#result').html($(this).find(":selected").val());
  var result = $('#result').html();  //Notice .html() instead of val()
  if(result == 'Gold') {
      $('select[name="Bolt On Options"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  }
});
```

Working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/xHrHA/2/

As pointed out in the comments this could all be simplified to:

```
$('select[name="Package Options"]').change(function() {
  $('#result').html($(this).find(":selected").val());   
  if($(this).val() == 'Gold') {
      $('select[name="Bolt On Options"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  }
});
```

Working Example: http://jsfiddle.net/xHrHA/3/

Comment: Perfect! Such a simple mistake haha, thank you so much. Will accept when SO will allow me :)

Comment: @AndyHolmes Glad I could help.  This one has tripped me up before also.

Comment: this is _not_ a good solution - you shouldn't be reading the `.html()` to find the value, it's already trivially available as `this.value`

Comment: @KevinBowersox don't forget that `$(this).val() === this.value`, the latter being much more efficient.

Answer (score 0):

try this

***JS CODE***

```
$('select[name="Package Options"]').change(function() {
  $('#result').html($(this).find(":selected").val());
  var result = $('#result').text();//use `text()` or `html()` instead of val()
  if(result == 'Gold') {
      $('select[name="Bolt On Options"]').attr('disabled', 'disabled');
  }
});
```

***[LIVE DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/xHrHA/4/)***

Comment: why this -1? can you explain please?

Comment: the -1 was for continuing to use the DOM to store the text variable when the right solution is to retrieve that variable directly from the `<select>` and then use it in the subsequent test.  The same applies to @RobWillis

Answer (score 0):

A div does not have a value property so val() cannot be used.  You will need to use .text() or .html() instead.

Answer (score -2):

try using

var result = $.trim('#result').val();